# Formatting date values for tooltips in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts graph that is displaying dates, but the tooltip header is displaying the date as (for example) 1477958400000 when I want it to say "Tuesday, Nov 1, 2016". How do I change the date format on the tooltip header?

UPDATE: Here is my Highcharts code:

```
Highcharts.chart('div-container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Balances'
    },

    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true,
      pointFormat: '<span style="font-weight: bold;color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',

      valueDecimals: 4
    },

    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal',

            lineColor: '#666666',
            lineWidth: 1, 

            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#666666'
            }
        }
    },

    series: contribution_type_balances_series
});
```

...and here is my data:

```
Date,Series1,Series2,Series3
2016-11-01,51133.8941,5709.6097,22837.8403
2016-11-02,50507.2502,5639.6387,22557.9634
2016-11-03,50967.3341,5644.3896,22576.977
2016-11-04,51310.3385,5663.6562,22654.0417
2016-11-05,51310.3385,5663.6562,22654.0417
2016-11-06,51310.3385,5663.6562,22654.0417
2016-11-07,52434.202,5787.7087,23150.239
2016-11-08,52607.4831,5806.8356,23226.7444
2016-11-09,53741.9039,5932.0534,23727.6028
2016-11-10,54068.759,5968.1318,23871.9127
2016-11-11,54068.759,5968.1318,23871.9127
2016-11-12,54068.759,5968.1318,23871.9127
2016-11-13,54068.759,5968.1318,23871.9127
2016-11-14,55476.6901,6123.5396,24493.53
2016-11-15,55483.3455,6124.2742,24496.4684
2016-11-16,55552.7511,6131.9353,24527.1117
2016-11-17,56104.0877,6147.0583,24587.6056
2016-11-18,56088.9295,6126.8777,24506.8854
```

Comment: Add your code here, possible cause is you are missing type:dateTime

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Balances'
    },


    data: {
      csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    },

    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        stacking: 'normal',

        lineColor: '#666666',
        lineWidth: 1,

        marker: {
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColor: '#666666'
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      lineWidth: 1
    }]
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/nry4qmn6/)**